# mysql выбор записи при условии что в указанной групе все поля с одинаковм значением

Tags: mysql

Приветсвую!
есть таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно выбрать по сути только local, при условии что у всех записей с local work_count=work_cur

в данном случае должно выдаться local 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно через такую конструкцию. В подзапросе выбираем все `local`, где `work_count` не равны `work_cur`, и проверяем, не входит ли в это множество каждый из `local`

```
SELECT DISTINCT `local` 
FROM Table1 
WHERE `local` NOT IN (SELECT `local` FROM Table1 WHERE `work_count` != `work_cur`);
```

```
local
1
```

[Пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa39f2/13)

Comment: Благодарю.. супер..